# To display a write error when the file to be replaced in destination is used by other applications while transfering using MQFTE?

Tags: ant, ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

If a file in destination which is to be replaced by another file is being used or modified by other applications, a write error should be displayed. Instead the file is replaced while transfering the file using mqfte.